# Highlight unique values within Subtotal groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight unique values withing each subgroup of Excel when I have done a count subtotal on a spreadsheet. For example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zDsaXN8.jpg]

In this instance I have selected two of the subgroups, column A in the first subgroup all have `20` so would not have any highlighted, however in the second subgroup `30` is a unique value in that group and therefore needs to be highlighted.

Is there a way of doing this with a macro, or possibly a conditional formatting formula?

Example Excel file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlp5znac2qqd8j7/Stackoverflow.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select ColumnA and try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,C1,A:A,A1)=1
```

Comment: Hi, it did something, but it didnt highlight just the Unique values... i.imgur.com/0WjejNi.jpg

Comment: Not having much luck with that one unfortunately... http://i.imgur.com/G6Pg5jT.jpg

Comment: That did work a second time around, i have no idea what i was doing wrong the first time, however thank you so much, that is going to be an amazing help

Answer (score 0):

Here are screen captures that should make it obvious, I hope.

**Please note the "Applies To"** in the second screen shot: list all the cells you need to.

Tho get to VBA code, record a macro while doing it by hand and use the recorded code as a basis for you REAL code to automate this task.

Good luck!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, i was hoping there would be a macro or similar to automate the process using a blank cell as the point to restart the formula. Maybe it was wishful thinking....

Comment: I've got to see the sample worksheet. It appears you need to just write some VBA code to find unique values in each group and highlight those. This sub should be triggerd either from a Worksheet_Change event or Worksheet_SelectionChange event of with a command. It is fortunate that the groups are deliniated with spaces (column A:A) so it's easy to know start/end of each group. The approach I presented above is not practical here, indeed.

Comment: I am not shure how the approach you've suggested would work at all since the subgroups in "A:A" do not have unique-to-them-only sets of values, that is "10" could be unique in one subgroup but it would appear in many others-->you have to look at subgroups individually. Also, I do not understand how column "C:C" is involved in all this. In any case, I do not see applying conditional formatting to cells is productive: it is heavy and it bloats the size of the file.